# Location Manager for tracking user location with best accuracy in iOS

Tags: ios, gps, location, cllocationmanager

I am using Location Manager in my app for tracking user's location and displaying route on Map. I am calculating pace and distance also.

But i always see my location jumping around on the Map even when i am sitting at the same position.

How can i improve the tracking?

I am using "kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation" for desired accuracy. Distance filter is set to 10 meters.

Looking farward for answers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you indoors or outdoors? In a city or an open (tall buildings) or open space

Comment: it shows same behaviour whether i am inside or outside.

Comment: Location is affected by the quality of the gps radio signals. Tall buildings cause the signal to bounce around, giving unstable location.

Comment: Ya thats true.
but how to filter out correct locations, and implement a Navigation tracking logic.

Comment: You could try averaging the location or try to ignore locstion updates where there are sudden large changes in location or speed

Comment: Can you suggest how do I average the locations?